# Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are random variables, is $E[Y|Z, X \in \mathcal{X}]= E[Y|Z, I(X \in \mathcal{X})=1]?$

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are random variables. Suppose $X$ is a positive discrete variable. Let $\mathcal{X}=\{1, 2, 3\}$ denote a subset of values that $X$ can take. My question is, is
$$E[Y|Z, X \in \mathcal{X}]= E[Y|Z, I(X \in \mathcal{X})=1]?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X \in \mathcal X$, $I(X \in \mathcal X) = 1$, or even something silly like $\prod_{k \in \mathcal X} (X - k) = 0$ are all just variously cumbersome ways to describe the same event. And the expected value $\mathbb E[Y \mid Z, A]$ should not depend on how you describe the event $A$, only on what that event is.